# file doesnt exists in routes Http directory laravel 5

Tags: php, python, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have a python script beside 'routes.php' and I want to execute that from 'routes.php'  file .
when i use exec() function it does not work correctly .
so , i try `file_exists()` :

```
Route::get('/py', function(){
    if (file_exists( "new.py" ))
        echo "succeed";
    else
        echo "failed";
});
```

it only returns failed , so how can I get output from .py file via exec function ?

Comment: what is path of `new.py` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the absolute path, try with

```
 file_exists(__DIR__.'/new.py')
```

Assuming that it is in the same directory as routes.php

Comment: Yes, I did read beside routes.php as it is in the same folder. If it is not it is still easier to build the path to it with a known starting point using `__DIR__`

Comment: Thank you , That Worked , another question , for example what if my file was in views folder ?

Comment: To get to the views folder you need to go up to folders and then include the path to views. `file_exists(__DIR__.'/../../resources/views/new.py')` `__DIR__` is directory of the file you run the code from, so you can build the path to any file from it in the same way as you do on command line

Comment: Thank You Again , excuse me another question , I'm trying to print a value in my py file , how can i get that output and show that in php ?

Comment: You need to send in an extra parameter to exec, and that parameter will be filled with any result from your py file http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: must i use return function in my python function ? or only print is enough ?

Comment: The spec say $output will be filled with every line of output, so in theory print should be enough. But you have to try to verify that it actually work

Answer (score 0):

The file path you are giving is not correct. **file_exists()** will check the file inside the **public** folder in laravel. If you are placed the **py** inside your public folder , then give the exact path to the file.